# CSS animate Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events, animate.css

I am trying to install some Javacript to make my animation run more than once.

I have been given this script off the animate site but have no idea where to actually include the element that I want it to apply the animation to.

I wish to apply the animation 'animated zoomIn' to both the h2 and h3 headings that are in a div with the class of thumbtitle-box.

Here is my html:

```
div class="imagethumbnailleft">
                <div class="thumbtitle-box"><h2>ARTFUL DODGER TRADING COMPANY</h2><h3>- Illustrated playing card series -</h3></div>
```

Here is my CSS:

```
    .animated {
      -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
      animation-duration: 1s;
      -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
      animation-fill-mode: both;
    }

@-webkit-keyframes zoomIn {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: scale3d(.3, .3, .3);
    transform: scale3d(.3, .3, .3);
  }

  50% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes zoomIn {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: scale3d(.3, .3, .3);
    transform: scale3d(.3, .3, .3);
  }

  50% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.zoomIn {
  -webkit-animation-name: zoomIn;
  animation-name: zoomIn;
}
```

And the Javascript - which is what the problem is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

function animationHover(trigger, element, animation){
    element = $(element);
    trigger = $(trigger);
    trigger.hover(
        function() {
            element.addClass('animated ' + 'zoomIn');          
        },
        function(){
            //wait for animation to finish before removing classes
            window.setTimeout( function(){
                element.removeClass('animated ' + animation);
            }, 2000);           
        });
}

});
```

I am completely new to Javascript and any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

May be you are looking for this:

work for h2 and h3 tag under thumbtitle-box class

`$(".imagethumbnailleft  h2, .imagethumbnailleft  h3").hover(function(){
        animationHover(this,this,'zoomIn');
    });`

http://jsfiddle.net/a7r95y7x/2/

Comment: Thanks for this - it works perfectly on all the other h2 and h3's on my site but not the ones within the <div class="imagethumbnailleft">

Comment: I tried attaching an id to the h2 and h3 but that didn't work either.

Comment: Unfortunately, it still does not work. I have no idea why. I inserted the above revised script and nothing happens. Thanks though

Comment: could you check all the 3 versions http://jsfiddle.net/a7r95y7x/, http://jsfiddle.net/a7r95y7x/1/, http://jsfiddle.net/a7r95y7x/2/

Comment: I've realised what the problem is. The .thumbtitlebox div has 'pointer-events:none;' applied to it. I cant remove this because when I do, the fade attribute doesn't work on hover for the div below it as the pointer is blocked.

Comment: I didn't think this was the problem as when I apply the animated zoomIn affect using css only, it works perfectly, despite the 'pointer-events:none;' .

I only need to switch to javascript because I need to apply a remove class so it works properly in firefox (runs mulitple times on hover, nit just once)